# How can I change my code for it to be presented on the screen?

Tags: python, pygame, pong

```
def victory_screen():
  while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        quit_game()

    screen.fill(WHITE)
    largeText = pygame.font.Font(None,50)
    screen.blit(largeText.render("Congratulations!",True,BLUE),(135,40))
    largeText = pygame.font.Font(None,35)
    screen.blit(largeText.render("You have completed the game!", True, BLUE), (205,90))
    button("Try Beat me again", 130, 250, 150, 60, RED, GREEN, menu)
    button("Quit", 130, 250, 150, 60, RED, GREEN, quit_game)

    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(frame_rate)

def instructions_screen():
  while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        quit_game()

    screen.fill(WHITE)

    largeText = pygame.font.Font(None,50)
    smallText = pygame.font.Font(None, 35)

    screen.blit(largeText.render("Instructions", True, BLUE), (181, 50))
    screen.blit(smallText.render("Goal of the game: Reach to 7 points first", True, BLACK), (148, 150))
    screen.blit(smallText.render("How to move: Upper arrow - up", True, BLACK), (148, 210))
    screen.blit(smallText.render("Lower arrow - down", True, BLACK), (429, 250))

    button("Play", 240, 250, 150, 60, GREEN, BLACK, menu)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

def front_page():
  next_screen = None

  def start_game():
    nonlocal next_screen
    next_screen = menu

    while True:
      for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
          quit_game()

      if next_screen is not None:
        return next_screen

    screen.fill(WHITE)

    screen.blit(image1, (0,0))

    largeText = pygame.font.Font(None, 65)
    screen.blit(largeText.render("Wizard mania", True, BLUE),(240,50))

    button("Start", 225, 200, 150, 60, GREEN, BLACK, start_game)
    button("Quit", 225,250, 150, 60, GREEN, BLACK, quit_game)

    button("Controls", 225, 300, 150, 60, GREEN, BLACK, instructions_screen)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(frame_rate)

def menu():
  vel = 4

  ply1 = pygame.Rect(40, 45, 30, 30)
  keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
  
  scoreA = 0
  scoreB = 0
  

  lefthandwalls = [
      LeftHandwall(0, 545, 10, 5)
  ]
  righthandwalls = [
      RightHandwall(0, 545, 10, 5)
    ]

  while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        quit_game

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and ply1.y > 0:
      ply1.y -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and ply1.y < 600 - ply1.height:
      ply1.y += vel

    for lefthandwalls in LeftHandwall:
      if ply1.colliderect(lefthandwalls):
        scoreB = scoreB + 1
        print(scoreB)

      if ply1.colliderect(righthandwalls):
        scoreA = scoreA + 1
        print(scoreA)

      if scoreA == 7:
        print("You have won the game")
        victory_screen

      screen.fill(WHITE)

      for lefthandwalls in LeftHandwall:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, lefthandwalls)

      for righthandwalls in RightHandwall:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, righthandwalls)

      pygame.display.flip()
      clock.tick(60)

def main():
  scene = front_page
  while scene is not None:
    scene = scene()

main()
pygame.quit()
```

I am coding a ping pong game in pygame for my computer science project. I expected that the game will start from the front page and when "start" pressed it goes to the game, or when "controls" pressed a tutorial will show and lastly "quit" pressed it closes the game. However, I get only a black screen

Comment: I have correct the code, but i still have a black screen

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: I don't know if this is an copy-paste error but you're defining `start_game()` inside `front_page()` but you're never calling `start_game()` elsewhere but inside itself, which will never execute

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the `front_page` function:

<s>`scene = front_page`</s>

```py
scene = front_page()
```